# Use a variable to pick which partial to use

Tags: handlebars.js, assemble, static-site

I'm looking to load a partial based on a variable that is in the front matter data of the content page that i have. I've been able to get handlebars to pass back the correct variable name from in side the page but it will not then process the resulting string as a request to a partial:

```
<div class="sub-column">{{> (rhs1) }}</div>
```

this then just outputs the content of the variable rather than then going to find the partial it is referring to. I have also tried is using {{{ }}} but this has not helped.

Is this possible or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Is rhs1 a function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use a helper function to return the partial:

```
fs.readFileSync('src/partials/'+content+'.html', 'utf8');
```

this then allowed the system to recognise that we wanted to point to the partial.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me this is your issue ...

From the documentation available here : http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html

Subexpressions do not resolve variables so whichPartial must be a function. If a simple variable has the partial name, it's possible to resolve it via the lookup helper.

```
{{> (lookup . 'myVariable') }}
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get the lookup to work. it would pass back the variable but then not recognise the outer call to be a reference to a partial. it would just output the brackets and then the name of the partial file I was referencing